# insert a Wordpress page content into a pop up

Tags: login

Is it possible to include a page content into a popup to login users when they click in a specific button ?
Thanks

Comment: Please try to be more specific - what content do you want in the popup ( is it the login form ? ) - what button, what pages is it shown on etc.?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to create a custom template without get_header and get_footer. Copy page.php to custom.php. on top write the template name.

Than make an Ajax call (register an Ajax action first). Requesting the url with your custom template.